# Troubles using fstream in a class

Tags: c++, fstream

I get the following error, when compiling:

```
1>c:\users\ra\source\repos\sandbox\game\gamesetup_1\gamesetup_1\main.cpp(15): error C2280: 'DebugLib::DebugLib(const DebugLib &)': attempting to reference a deleted function
1>c:\users\ra\source\commonincludes\tannic\debuglib\debuglib.h(41): note: compiler has generated 'DebugLib::DebugLib' here
1>c:\users\ra\source\commonincludes\tannic\debuglib\debuglib.h(41): note: 'DebugLib::DebugLib(const DebugLib &)': function was implicitly deleted because a data member invokes a deleted or inaccessible function 'std::basic_fstream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::basic_fstream(const std::basic_fstream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &)'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.16.27023\include\fstream(1421): note: 'std::basic_fstream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::basic_fstream(const std::basic_fstream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &)': function was explicitly deleted
1>Done building project "GameSetup_1.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
```

The code looks like this:

DebugLib.h:

```
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

class DebugLib
{
public:
    DebugLib();             // Reset timestamp etc. 
    ~DebugLib();            // Flush output buffer
    void Init(uint8_t output, std::string fileName = "debug.log");  // Initializes Log
    void Log(int category, std::string msg);    // Add a line to the log
    void Flush();           // Output the remains of the Debug buffer
    void Shutdown();        // Shut it down

private:
    unsigned int m_initTime;

    unsigned int m_bufferPos;
    std::string m_outputBuffer[DEBUG_MAXSIZE];

    std::fstream m_fileStream;

    uint8_t m_output;
    bool m_running;
};
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <DebugLib.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    DebugLib gDebugger = DebugLib();

    gDebugger.Init(DEBUG_LOG_TO_SCREEN);

    cout << "Running!" << endl;
    gDebugger.Shutdown(); 
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

As soon as I declare `m_fileStream` I get the error. Do I have a wrong declaration ? 
When I remove all the use of `m_fileStream` in `DebugLib.cpp`, the code compiles fine, and runs (but of course not as attended)

Comment: A [two line duplication of your error](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/31af4e70b877e076).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*I couldn't find a duplicate even though I've seen this asked before, so:*

Let's start by explaining the error messages. I'll ignore the line numbers and error codes, as those are rarely useful until after you've understood (or at least read) the rest of the error message.

> ```
> 'DebugLib::DebugLib(const DebugLib &)': attempting to reference a deleted function
> ```

This is the main error: an attempt to use a function that is deleted, namely the copy constructor for `DebugLib`. Since you did not explicitly specify a copy constructor, it is up to the compiler to define one for you. The compiler will define a naive copy if possible. If this definition is not possible, it will delete the copy constructor for you.

As you noticed, the compiler is able to define a naive copy until you add a field that cannot be copied (such as `std::fstream`).

> ```
> note: compiler has generated 'DebugLib::DebugLib' here
> ```

This is a clarifying note that helps the error refer to two lines in your program. The line number that came with the main error message is where you tried to do the copy, and the line number that comes with this note is where the copy constructor is generated. The compiler is trying to be helpful because it doesn't know which location you'll want to change to address this error.

> ```
> note: 'DebugLib::DebugLib(const DebugLib &)': function was implicitly deleted because a data member invokes a deleted or inaccessible function 'std::basic_fstream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::basic_fstream(const std::basic_fstream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &)'
> ```

This note explains the thing you noticed: copying your class is prevented because the `std::fstream` member cannot be copied. This message uses the name `basic_fstream` at this point, so it helps to know that `fstream` is an instantiation of the `basic_fstream` template. So that mess of code at the end of this note just names the copy constructor of `std::fstream`.

> ```
> note: 'std::basic_fstream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::basic_fstream(const std::basic_fstream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &)': function was explicitly deleted
> ```

This is a further clarification. The line before this said "deleted or inaccessible". This line clarifies that to "explicitly deleted".

Now that we have read the error, we can go look at the lines to which it refers. The troublesome line is

> ```
>   DebugLib gDebugger = DebugLib();
> ```

This line requests that a `DebugLib` object be default constructed then copied to `gDebugger`. And there's the problem: it cannot be copied! The solution is to simplify your logic by removing the copy. You can invoked the default constructor directly on `gDebugger`. (This works for other constructors as well, should your code need them.)

```
    DebugLib gDebugger{};
```

As a bonus, your code is shorter.

Comment: Fun fact: Due to the compiler being smarter than the average bear, the copy would be elided and, if copying was possible, not happen at all. It must still be legal to copy, even if the copy is optimized out.

Comment: @user4581301 That is quite true. I just wasn't sure if I should include that tidbit in this answer. ;)

Comment: Not relevant to the answer, but it makes a good comment. I take 'em where I can get 'em. Thanks for the kick by the way. Looks like I forgot to upvote.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. You hit it right on the spot. After i edited it, everything works as planned !