# Adding fstream object to a vector

Tags: c++, vector, fstream

I have a similar problem to this:
[Troubles using fstream in a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58562775/troubles-using-fstream-in-a-class)

I clearly understand, that I can't copy a fstream object.

Now.. i want to have vector of structs, that includes a fstream. so i have created these typedefs:

```
typedef struct
{
    uint16_t output;
    std::string outputStr;
    std::fstream fileStream{};
} LogOutput;

typedef std::vector <LogOutput> vecLogOutput;
```

The problems then come when i try to add something to that vector:

```
vecLogOutput vLO;
LogOutput lo;

// CREATE 3 LogOutputs, and add them, to vector
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    lo.output = i;
    lo.outputStr = "fileout" + std::to_string(i) + ".txt";
    lo.fileStream.open(lo.outputStr, std::fstream::out | std::fstream::trunc);
    vLO.emplace_back(lo);
}
```

I guess that the only way to do it right, is having the vector filled will with references to LogOutput instead of the objects it self. And of course remember to delete the objects

Comment: Please add to the question which problems you encountered to save us some time. Unrelated hint: in c++ you don't need to `typedef` a struct, you can simply write `struct LogOutput`.

Answer (score 0):

[std::move](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move) is what you're looking for:

`vLO.emplace_back(std::move(lo));`

Comment: It was all it took. btw, i got it working with pointers too. but the endless "new" and "delete" and referencing would be a hell.... :) Thank You!

Comment: Well.. it worked in the first place.  But actually i need to add the vector to a map.. and then hell breaks loose again. i have a map<int,vecLogOutput> defined.

Comment: Found out, that it was later, when iterating through the map i had the problem. I started by: vecLogOutput vLO = m_outputMap[j]; ... and of course, that will copy it again. so i do that by reference now: vecLogOutput* vLO = &m_outputMap[j];

Comment: @tannic A lot of c-tendecies in your code. I suggest using `vecLogOutput& vLO = m_outputMap[j];` if you don't specifically need a raw pointer. Which I doubt.